# Spring AMQP request-response across 2 web applications

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I would like an example/sample code of 2 simple spring web/java applications where I need to send messages from the 1 and the 2nd application must receive the messages and respond back. I looked at few that had request/response in the same application but unable to separate them. I'm new to Amqp & RabbitMQ. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the [stock trading sample](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/sample-apps.html), [request reply messaging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply) (client side) and [MessageListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#async-consumer) which automatically handles request/reply on the server side (where your service is a POJO).